# Excel 2016 - How do I determine which column I should use to help me predict actual numbers?

Tags: excel, math, statistics, excel-2016

I have 3 columns that guess what a number should be, and then the actual column of what the numbers are.  I need to determine mathematically overall a few things.  (Each column is a prediction and there are 3 sources.)

1. Which column was the closest to the actual column.
2. Which column was the closest to the actual column, but was larger than the actual column.  (Supervisor would rather guess high than low.)
3. Which column should I use in assisting me predict the actual numbers for next year.

I'm not sure if I should use only Conditional Formatting, or have columns with the percentages of over / under.  What do you recommend and how would you do this?

[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use *root-mean-square* to evaluate each option.  For example, to compare cols **A** and **D**, use:

```
=SQRT(SUMPRODUCT((A2:A15-D2:D15)^2))
```

then compare **B** and **D**.  Finally compare **C** and **D**.

Use whichever column has the lowest *RMS* score.